# Has Inno Setup dropped support for images inside RTF files for Windows 10?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I've recently migrated from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and a specific issue has shown up in Inno installers.

Whenever I create an installer and use the directive `InfoBeforeFile` and specify a RTF file containing images, those images are not shown.

This began to happen after I migrated to Windows 10 LTSC.

I'm currently using Inno Setup Compiler version 6.2.1, but I'm also experiencing this on older versions too.

Has someone experienced the same?

Thanks.

Following is the code and some images.

Code Snipet:

```
#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"

[Setup]
AppId={{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
InfoBeforeFile=Pics.rtf
OutputDir=c:\
OutputBaseFilename=mysetup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Files]
Source: "*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

RTF File contents:
[image]

Output of Inno Installer:

[image]

Link to RTF file:
[Pics.RTF](https://mega.nz/file/Jq4FRKja#EMMUumAZkURMltgP3z8SXBnOexsPKt-w0lAL0t_yUdw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I open your .rtf file in WordPad, it displays this warning:

[image]

When I refuse to display the blocked contents, it does not display the images:

[image]

I'm sure that's the same reason, why the images do not display in Inno Setup. Make sure your document does not contain any untrusted contents.

---

After few tests, it seems that it is caused by images inserted into the document in Microsoft Word. Inserting the same images in WordPad cause no problems.